# Return parent value from dict of dicts if child key doesn't exist

Tags: python, dictionary, parent-child, parent

In my dictionary below, I want to be able to pull the `value` from my `subkey*` attributes. However, if a `subkey*` does not exist, I want to automatically return the parent's `value`.

```
d = {
'key1' : {
    'value': "parent-key1",
    'subkey1': {
        'value': "child1"
    },
    'subkey2': {
        'value': "child2"
    }
},
'key2': {
    'value': "parent-key2",
    'subkey1': {
        'value': "child3"
    },
    'subkey2': {
        'value': "child4"
    }
}
```

}

My function stub looks like this:

```
def get_values(my_dict_value):
    try:
        return my_dict_value
    except KeyError:
        # How do I find the parent value of my_dict_value?
```

My anticipated results are:

```
>>> get_values(d['key1']['subkey1']['value'])
child1
>>> get_values(d['key1']['subkey3']['value'])
parent-key1
```

How do I find the parent value in my dictionary?

Comment: The `KeyError` would be raised *before* you ever enter the function.  You probably want to pass the three keys you want to get from the dict to the function so you can catch the `KeyError` in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of solving it for nested dictionary with `get` method:

```
>>>
>>> d = {
... 'key1' : {
...     'value': "parent-key1",
...     'subkey1': {
...         'value': "child1"
...     },
...     'subkey2': {
...         'value': "child2"
...     }
... },
... 'key2': {
...     'value': "parent-key2",
...     'subkey1': {
...         'value': "child3"
...     },
...     'subkey2': {
...         'value': "child4"
...     }
... }}
>>>
>>> def get_value(key, subkey):
...     dkey = d.get(key)
...     return dkey.get(subkey, {}).get('value', dkey.get('value'))
...
>>> print get_value("key1", "subkey1")
child1
>>> print get_value("key2", "subkey2")
child4
>>> print get_value("key2", "subkey3")
parent-key2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As SethMMorton [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981771/return-parent-value-from-dict-of-dicts-if-child-key-doesnt-exist#comment40684837_25981771), your current method will throw a key error before it gets to the function.

You can get around this by passing two values to your function - the `parent` and the `child`. I dropped the third from needing to be passed because your example shows that both use the key of `value`. The function can handle that automatically.

```
def get_values(key, subkey):
    try:
        return d[key][subkey]['value']     
    except KeyError:
        try:
            return d[key]['value']
        except KeyError:
            return "Not found"
```

This utilizes nested exceptions, which will get very messy if you go much deeper than than. However, the outer `try` block attempts to return your `parent`/`child`/`value`. If this doesn't exist, it attempts to return the `parent`/`value`. If this doesn't exist, it returns `Not found`

You can call it like this:

```
print get_values("key1", "subkey1")
print get_values("key1", "subkey3")
print get_values("key4", "subkey1")
```

This outputs:

```
child1
parent-key1
Not found
```